# How to pass values of textboxes upon clicking a link?

Tags: jquery, function, textarea

I have two textareas. When the user clicks a text link, ie "Add to Cart", how would I get the values of both textareas to be pasted into a third textarea, separated by a delimiter like " -- ", and finally for a new page to load once the function is complete?

The code I have so far is:

JS:

```
$('#addtocart').click(function() {
var text1 = $("#inputA").val();
var text2 = $("#inputB").val();
var text3 = text1 + "\n--\n" + text2;
$("#personalisedmsg").val(text3);   
};
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="inputA" class="limited" rows="6">Your top message here.</textarea><br />
<textarea id="inputB" class="limited" rows="6">Your bottom message here.</textarea><br />
<textarea id="personalisedmsg"></textarea>

<br><br>

<a id="addtocart" href="#">Add to Cart.</a>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: new page load is ajax after text area is field?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: can you post some code over here??

Comment: The third textarea has variables assigned to it that will retain its contents for a shopping cart. Rory, I will edit the original post to show you what I'm tinkering with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the text field stuff...

```
var text1 = $("#textbox1").val();//textbox1 is the id value of the text area
var text2 = $("#textbox2").val();//textbox2 is the id value of the text area
var text3 = text1 + "\n--\n" + text2;
$("#textbox3").val(text3);//set the next text in textbox3
```

To load a new page doesnt make sense, what are you doing with textbox3 data before? Do you instead want to submit a form? If so, you can do like this for example (assuming only one form in document)...

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

or to just reload a new page if you really want to then...

```
window.location = 'newpage.html';//or whatever you page is called
```

**Important Note**

When you use the click handler of a link, if the link has a `href` property set you should ensure you are cancelling the default action (i.e. the reloading of a new page)...

```
$('#addtocart').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//cancel the new page load action

    //rest of code here
});
```

**Working Example**

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ct2G/)

note that after copying your JQuery code I had to add an additional close bracket `)` at the end for it to run correctly

Comment: Thank you for your post, I will try this too. Textbox3 is a textbox with predetermined properties set up by the eCommerce package I'm using, its contents will appear on the checkout page due to the way it has been set up, so I need to pass custom text into this box. The values of this box are retained when the user clicks 'Add to cart' and text is passed into it, however it will be hidden via CSS. Using this particular textbox is a requirement due to the way the eCommerce software works, but I need to offer multiple text boxes to the user, not just one.

Comment: Oh, and the new page part is needed to take the user to their shopping cart after the function is complete.

Comment: @Chris: OK, all sounds fine, hope you get what you need ;)

Comment: Almost there - text isn't appearing in the the third textbox, please could you take a look?

JS:
    $('#addtocart').click(function() {
    var text1 = $("#inputA").val();
    var text2 = $("#inputB").val();
    var text3 = text1 + "\n--\n" + text2;
    $("#personalisedmsg").val(text3);  
    }
});

HTML:
        <textarea id="personalisedmsg"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <a id="addtocart" href="#">Add to Cart</a>

Comment: @Chris: You should add any extra code to your original question as an edit

Comment: Ahh perfect, so it was just a missing bracket! That is spot on, thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

html:

```
<textarea name="text1"></textarea>
<textarea name="text2"></textarea>
<textarea name="text3"></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery('textarea[name=text3]').val(jQuery('textarea[name=text1]').val() + " --- SEP --- " + jQuery('textarea[name=text2]').val());

jQuery.post('yoururl.php');
// or
window.location = 'yoururl.php';
// or
jQuery('#yourform').submit();
```

Comment: I wouldn't personally use `.html` but anyway, just wanted to say you missed the separator requirement ;)

Answer (score 0):

set A tag attribute like below to move on new page with textbox value without submitting page.

```
$("#addtocart").click(function(e) {
var t1=$("#textbox1").val();
var t2=$("#textbox2").val();    
var t3=t1 + "--" + t2;
var url="your url"+"?id="+t3  
$(this).attr("href",url);
});
```